# Boolean expression - if 2 or more conditions True

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, boolean-logic

I'm trying to create a dplyr filter based on some conditions, say there are three conditions, condition1, condition2 and condition3.
I want it to evaluate overall as TRUE if ANY two or more conditions are TRUE,

Any idea how to do this easily in R? I can make a very long expression with each combination of conditions, but was hoping for something easier,

Many thanks

EDIT:

Reprex as requested

```
df %>%
filter(condition1|condition2|condition2)
```

I want the subset of df where two or greater of the conditions above are true

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: You can sum boolean expressions like `t= c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE);  sum(t)`. Then you can make a single boolean  where `sum(t)` is greater than or equal to 2.

Comment: You need to add a sample of the set you are filtering as well as the output you wish to receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` approach.  You can also use `rowwise` and `c_across` if you want to be strictly tidyverse-y about it.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(a = c(T, T, F), b = c(F, T, T), c = c(T, F, F))

df
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  a     b     c     truth_ct
  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>    <dbl>
1 TRUE  FALSE TRUE         2
2 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE        2
3 FALSE TRUE  FALSE        1
```

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(truth_ct = rowSums(.)) %>% 
  filter(truth_ct >= 2)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  a     b     c     truth_ct
  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>    <dbl>
1 TRUE  FALSE TRUE         2
2 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE        2
```

`rowwise` approach:

```r
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(truth_ct = sum(c_across(a:c))) %>% 
  filter(truth_ct >= 2)
```

Comment: Thanks I ended up finding out about rowwise, I didn't know about c_across though, very useful

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   filter(reduce(cur_data(), `+`) >=2)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  a     b     c    
  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
2 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
```